# Curly brackets automatically placing itself around a text string?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I use a canvas text and some curly brackets keep forming around my output.

I have no idea how this works so I don't know what to try.

```
self.canvas.create_text(x/2, y/1.05, fill="white", font=("res/KeepCalm-Medium.ttf", 25),
                        text=("Sender: ", "5005"))
self.canvas.pack(side='top', expand=True)
```

The output is following:

{Sender: } 5005

But i want it to look like this:

Sender: 5005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma in `text=("Sender: ", "5005")` changes it to tuple from string hence the brackets. Remove the comma and concatenate using + if you want the trailing number to be dynamic :

```
text=("Sender: "+str(Sender_ID))
```